# How to get information out of a java applet?

Tags: java, applet

I've a simple webpage with a java applet.
The applet calculated a few values. (up to 30 lines of text)
Then I want to send the values back to the server.

Sorry for my english and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use URL and URLConnection (or HTTPUrlConnection)

[Reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just do a GET / POST HTTP call to your webserver with the value as parameter. You should have any server side programming language in order to process those parameters.

Comment: how to do a post http call of an applet?